# Is Windows Phone 7 User interface based on Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, user-interface, windows-phone-7

I've heard that Windows Phone 7's user interface (UI) is completely based on Silverlight. Can anybody confirm this? Or it is implemented by other frameworks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 will support developing apps in [either Silverlight or XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402531(v=VS.92).aspx).

Are you asking if the shell, etc that comes on the phone itself is written in Silverlight?  My first question would be "why does it matter what Microsoft used?"  It's probably a good bet that they leveraged it, but I doubt they did everything in SL.  At some point they have to get down to the OS.  For example, I doubt the built-in media player core or Office apps are SL.

Looking at the [unlocked emulator image contents](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=606) would certainly let you deduce which parts were developed with what technologies.  I leave that exercise to you.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed Silverlight is used for third-party apps on Windows Phone 7, plus XNA is supported too as mentioned. 
However the Office apps and some first-party applications are written using the Iris framework which is an internal only developer framework similar to WPF, it is the same framework used for the Zune Software (Dorado) which is used to sync to a Windows Phone 7 device.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is based on Silverlight

Comment: Thank you, would you please provide me a reference about it?

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you one thing, they are using Expression Blend (or a modified version of it) for parts of the core UI design. You can see the developers using this on one of their promo videos.